# SQL Server Ce 2005 Data Conversion fails based on data in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like :

```
    select * from table where varchar_column=Numeric_value
```

that is fine until I run an insert script. After the new data is inserted, I must use this query:

```
    select * from table where varchar_column='Numeric_value'
```

Can inserting a certain kind of data cause it to no longer implicitly convert?
After the insert script, the error is Data conversion fails OLEDB Status = 2
And the second query does work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain of this... the first may be doing an implicit conversion of the varchar_column to a numeric value. Not the other way around.  But when you insert values into that column that's no longer convertable, it fails.  However, with the second, you're doing a varchar to varchar comparison and all is right again with the world.  My guess.

Comment: That sounds like it would try to convert the column value into a number as opposed to converting the number_value into a varchar and comparing that to the column value - that seems like whats its doing

Comment: Especially , now I've found in my insert script data that has characters in the varchar_column - thus it cannot be converted into a number

Comment: it is a bit strange but it does make sense if you think about it.  the comparison is more likely to be correct if you go from varchar to decimal/numeric instead of the other way around... since 1.1 can be represented in an infinite varchar values... ie. 1.10, 1.100, 1.1000 etc.